# footnote for bibliography section title

Tags: sectioning, bibliographies, footnotes

I would like to add a footnote to the title of the bibliography (using bibtex). It would look something like this:

---

Bibliography*

1. reference 1
2. reference 2

etc.

*This is a footnote for Bibliography.

---

How to do this?

The bibliography without the footnote is generated by:

```
\bibliographystyle{bst-file-name}
\bibliography{bibtex-database-file}
```

I use article class with natbib, tocloft and tocbibind packages.

Comment: Are you using packages such as `natbib` for the bibliography? What's the document class you're using? Such information is crucial.

Comment: @egreg I have edited the question to include this informaton.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your setup, the patch is sufficiently easy. The biggest problem is not propagating the footnote to the table of contents.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Lam94,
  author =    {L. Lamport},
  title =     {{\LaTeX}---A Document Preparation System---User's Guide and Reference Manual},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  year =      1994,
  edition =   {2nd},
  note =      {Updated for {\LaTeXe}},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}


%%% Code for adding the footnote
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\toc@section}
  {\prw@mkboth}
  {\BIBFOOTNOTE\prw@mkboth}
  {}{}
\AtBeginEnvironment{thebibliography}{%
  \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\@fnsymbol{1}}%
}
\makeatother
%%% Here you define the footnote text
\newcommand\BIBFOOTNOTE{%
  \footnote{It would be better not having a footnote to the bibliography.}%
}
%%%

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Title}
In his book \cite{lam94}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

(The picture has been taken with a reduced text height.)

[image]

Comment: Happy accidence you were citing Lam94 ;-)

Answer (score 3):

One way to achieve this is to patch the `\thebibliography` environment (starter command), such that `\section*{\refname}` is changed to `\section*{\refname\footnote{some text}}`.

This does no harm to the toc, since `\section*{}` does not appear there (in a normal setup).

I additionally changed the footnotesymbol to `*`. However, this does only yield an asterisk, if the footnote counter is zero so far ;-)

If the document class is `book`, than `\section*{\refname}` has to be changed to `\chapter*{\bibname}`, however

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{localbib.bib}
@Book{GSM97,
  AUTHOR = {Michel Goossens and Sebastian Rahtz and Frank Mittelbach},
  TITLE = {{T}he {\LaTeX} {G}raphics {C}ompanion},
  PUBLISHER = "Addison-Wesley",
  YEAR = 1997
}

@Book{Lam94,
  author =   {L. Lamport},
  title =    {{\LaTeX}---A Document Preparation System---User's Guide and Reference Manual},
  publisher =    {Adsison-Wesley},
  year =     1994,
  edition =  {2nd},
  note =     {Updated for {\LaTeXe}}
}
\end{filecontents}

\newcommand{\BibliographyFootnoteText}{My super sophisticated footnote}

\xpatchcmd{\thebibliography}{\section*{\refname}}{\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}\section*{\refname\footnote{\BibliographyFootnoteText}}}{}{}


\begin{document}
In his book \cite{lam94}

\clearpage

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{localbib}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Of course my solution is no longer valid, since the OP uses a different setup