# How to insert a footnote in the bibliography heading

Tags: footnotes

I would like to put a footnote on my bibliography title generated with \bibliography{filename.bib).

Something like this:

References^1

reference 1

reference 2
etc.

1 This is a footnote for Bibliography.

I've been trying to do that for a while, but nothing.

I'm using the package abntex2 for the bibliography.

I've tried the solution proposed by egreg on [footnote for bibliography section title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232380/footnote-for-bibliography-section-title?answertab=active#tab-top) but it didn't work for me.

If anyone can help me on this, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Wouldn't inserting an introductory text block above the first reference have essentially the same effect?  If that's not acceptable, you can patch the text for the name of the bibliography, using `\footnotemark` and insert `\footnotetext` before the first reference.  (You will also need to pay attention to the running heads.)

Comment: Hi, Barbara. Thanks for your help.
And I really need to use a footnote as I mentioned, it is a standard that I need to follow.
I found a way to put a footnote in the reference title in my .cls file that i use:

\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]%
{%
   \if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi%
   \thispagestyle{\chaptertitlepagestyle}%
   \global\@topnum\z@%
   \@afterindentfalse%



   \chapter*{\References\protect\footnotemark{}\protect\footnotetext{Some footnote text}}
.
.
.

Comment: But, the issue now is that the footnote has been taken  to the toc.
I tried: 

\chapter*{References\except{toc}{\protect\footnotemark{}\protect\footnotetext{The first footnote}}}

But it didn't work. Any advice?

Comment: How starred chapter headings are added to the toc depends intimately on the document class used, and you haven't identified that.  In any event, the `\footnotetext` *never* should go into the chapter heading.  It should instead be the first input after `\begin{thebibliography}`.